# How to add a video iframe in background of section?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a section in my HTML for which I want to add a video that will be played automatically in the background but I am not able to do it. I added where the section starts but it is not getting added in the background instead getting added from the top.

Here is the iframe that I want to add:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="400" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
```

and here is my fiddle link [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o0d86c4h/1/).

Comment: http://codepen.io/anchen/pen/CcDkH

Comment: @AlexWilson How to add this into background of my fiddle?

Comment: take http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gknJj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdmgB)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page With Youtube Video Background</title>
<style>
body{ margin:0px; background:#000; }
#bg_container{ height:500px; overflow:hidden; }
#bg{ width:100%; height:900px; }
#content{ position:absolute; top:0px; padding:30px; color:#FFF; text-shadow:#000 2px 2px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bg_container">
  <iframe id="bg" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/LuD3_umIxgw?autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;loop=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;disablekb=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playlist=PLAYLIST_ID_HERE" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <h1>Web page with HD looping video background</h1>
  <h2>Using CSS the video is simply placed underneath our HTML content</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to take one example of what I wrote and change the fact that you need to

Answer (score -3):

Fast forward to 2019.... the link is Broken :(

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)